# Javascript: Use object in ES6 class as member and static object

Tags: javascript, class, static, instance, member

I have run into a issue lately.

I have a javascript class written in ES6.

There should be a static object. This object should also be available for class methods without defining it twice.

I tried to set the class member (property) to the static member in the constructor, but it throws an error:

Is there any way?

```
//Benötigt Bibliotheken: W3.css, W3.js

'use strict';

class Status {
    constructor(type, headerText, message){
        this.type = type;
        statusHeader.innerHTML = headerText;
        statusText.innerHTML = message;
        this.types = Status.types;  //set the instance member to the static member.

        this.setColor();
        this.setStyle();
    }

    setStyle() {
        //Alle Farbklassen entfernen.
        w3.removeClass('#' + status.id, Object.values(this.colors).join(" ") );

        //Farbklasse setzen.
        w3.addClass( '#' + status.id, this.color );
    }

    show() {
        w3.show('#' + status.id);
    }

    hide(){
        w3.hide('#' + status.id);
    }

    setColor() {
        switch(this.type){
            case this.types.info:
                this.color = this.colors.blue;
                break;
            case this.types.success:
                this.color = this.colors.green;
                break;
            case this.types.warning:
                this._color = this.colors.yellow;
                break;
            case this.types.error:
                this._color = this.colors.red;
                break;
        }
    }

    static colors(){ 
        return {
            'blue': 'w3-light-blue',
            'green': 'w3-light-green',
            'yellow': 'w3-light-yellow',
            'red': 'w3-light-red'
        };
    }
    static types(){
        return {
            'info': info,
            'success': success,
            'warning': warning,
            'error': error
        };
    }

/*  get colors(){ return this.colors; }

    get types(){ return this.types; } */
}

//Test class
alert(Status.types.info);   //Alert: 'undefined'
alert(new Status('info', 'Header', 'Message').types.info);  //Error: Status.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Comment: What's wrong with `Status.types()`? Why do you insist, that `this.types()` has to work?

Comment: `types` is a static method. You need to call it `this.types = Status.types()`. Not sure why you're doing it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any need for `types` to be a function. This works:

```js
class Status {
  constructor() {
    this.types = Status.types;
  }

  static types = {
    'info': 'info',
  };
}


const foo = new Status();
console.log(foo.types);
```

Comment: Note, that static properties are not widely supported yet. Works on V8, but not everywhere.

Comment: Wow, you guys are great.
mbojko's solution did the trick!

Great thx.

Answer (score 0):

After the class definition add static members..

```
class Status {
....
}

Status.types = {
    ...
}
```